# Allign Parent Bottom in Relative Layout doesn't works sometime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Relative Layout's layout and layout1 are used to display adds, top add is working perfectly but bottom add sometimes displayed at the bottom and sometime its displayed between the center and the bottom of the screen, I don't know what's wrong

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/zbackground" >
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
  </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/layout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
   </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/about_text1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is always adviced to post your xml code for a better understandings

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

after

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
       android:text="@string/about_text1"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#ffffffff"
       android:textSize="20dip" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20dip" />


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20dip" />
```

Comment: Lalit : do you know answer to the question I asked above?